# How to do set status to false during REST Call which returns a List

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to Spring , so please excuse if this is a wrong question .

I am developing REST Services using Spring boot .

I have developed a Get Request Service as shown below

```
@GetMapping("articles")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Article>> getAllArticles() {
        List<Article> list = articleService.getAllArticles();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Article>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

THis works fine , but if in case there is any exception how can i; send it to User (Ajax call) Hpw to set status to false ??

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely three options for handling errors in spring web:

1. Annotating exceptions with `@ResponseStatus` which, when such exceptions are thrown from your controller methods, the returned HTTP response status code would be determined from the `@ResponseStatus`.
2. Controller exception handling by annotating methods inside the controller with `@ExceptionHandler`. Every such exception handler is responsible for handling the declared exception. So, whenever this exception is thrown from inside your controller methods, this handler is invoked. Note that these handlers will not be invoked when exceptions are thrown by methods from **other** controllers.
3. Global error handling using `@ControllerAdvice`. This is similar to 2 in that it is a class having methods annotated with `@ExceptionHandler` but is not a controller. Therefore, these handlers will be invoked for any handled exception thrown by **any** controller.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the following statement

> return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);